# How to make a property value blinking?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property called `ResultChanged` that bound a `DataGrid` item, and when the value is `true` the `style` applied on the `DataGridCell` will colorize the `cell`, so I need to blink the `Cell` of the `DataGrid` settings for 5 times the value of `ResultChanged` to true and false, this is my xaml design:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource hour}" Binding="{Binding Result}">
 <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultChanged}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
      </DataTrigger>
    <Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

I tried to implement the logic in this way:

```
int i = 0;
bool blinkOn = false;

while (true)
{
    if(!blinkOn)
    {
        mtc.ResultChanged = true;
        blinkOn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        mtc.ResultChanged = false;
        blinkOn = true;
    }

    i++;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    //Stop blinking after 5 times
    if (i == 5)
        break;
}
```

the problem is that the `Cell` will always colorized and I don't see any blinking, any idea?

Comment: You could use a [WPF Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954490/880990) instead of struggling with implementing your own timing system.

Comment: Exactly. The two things you should *never* have in a UI application (or at least not in a UI thread) are `while (true)` and `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: Thanks guys for this precious hints, the answer of dhilmatty is the perfect solution, could you please check also this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223425/how-to-change-property-value-after-specific-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this style for your `DataGridCell` ?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource hour}" Binding="{Binding Result}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultChanged}" Value="True" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="Blink" 
                                    AutoReverse="True" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="5x">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                                     Value="Orange" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                                     Value="Black" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

The above style will `AutoReverse` itself. If you want to have the Orange color stay after the animation, you can set `AutoReverse` to `False`. But this will not get the same *Easing* action on reverse.

If you prefer to have the *Easing* action on reverse, you can introduce another action (`StoryBoard`) to do that after the intial `StoryBoard` completes at *00:00:10*. Like,

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource hour}" Binding="{Binding Result}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResultChanged}" Value="True" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="Blink" 
                                        AutoReverse="True" 
                                        RepeatBehavior="5x">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                                         Value="Orange" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                                         Value="Black" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard AutoReverse="False">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="Orange" />
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

You can play around the `AutoReverse` and `BeginTime` to your animation preference.

Comment: wow amazing effect, but I want ask you: can I keep the color orange after that the blinking is finished? For example: blinking start because the ResultChanged is true, and after the five blinking the color orange remain on the cell, is this possible? Could you please show me how? I really enjoyed this, thanks

Comment: I found a bug on this implementation, if I click on an row of the datagrid the orange effect will disappear, could you confirm that? How can I fix this? Thanks..